# Find nearest safe split in byte array containing UTF-8 data

Tags: c#, string, encoding, utf-8

I want to split a large array of UTF-8 encoded data, so that decoding it into chars can be parallelized.

It seems that there's no way to find out how many bytes `Encoding.GetCharCount` reads. I also can't use `GetByteCount(GetChars(...))` since it decodes the entire array anyways, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Get the total byte count, then decide how many sections to split into, grab `bytes[byteCount / sectionCount]` and test if it's a safe split position (if not, increment or decrement as appropriate to a safe position) then do the same for remaining groups.

Comment: And “safe” is anywhere that's not immediately before a continuation byte (i.e., between 0x80 and 0xBF).  Unless you need to keep grapheme clusters together, which makes things much more complicated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UTF-8 has well-defined byte sequences and is considered **self-synchronizing**, meaning given any position in `bytes` you can find where the character at that position begins at.

The UTF-8 spec ([Wikipedia is the easiest link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)) defines the following byte sequences:

```
0_______ : ASCII (0-127) char
10______ : Continuation
110_____ : Two-byte character
1110____ : Three-byte character
11110___ : Four-byte character
```

So, the following method (or something similar) should get your result:

1. Get the byte count for `bytes` (`bytes.Length`, et. al.)
2. Determine how many sections to split into
3. Select byte `byteCount / sectionCount`
4. Test byte against table:

   1. If `byte & 0x80 == 0x00` then you can make this byte part of either section
   2. If `byte & 0xE0 == 0xC0` then you need to seek ahead one byte, and keep it with the current section
   3. If `byte & 0xF0 == 0xE0` then you need to seek ahead two bytes, and keep it with the current section
   4. If `byte & 0xF8 == 0xF0` then you need to seek ahead three bytes, and keep it with the current section
   5. If `byte & 0xC0 == 0x80` then you are in a continuation, and should seek ahead until the first byte that does not fit `val & 0xB0 == 0x80`, then keep up to (but not including) this value in the current section
5. Select `byteStart` through `byteCount + offset` where `offset` can be defined by the test above
6. Repeat for each section.

Of course, if we redefine our test as returning the *current* char start position, we have two cases:
 1. If `(byte[i] & 0xC0) == 0x80` then we need to move around the array
 2. Else, return the current `i` (since it's **not** a continuation)

This gives us the following method:

```csharp
public static int GetCharStart(ref byte[] arr, int index) =>
    (arr[index] & 0xC0) == 0x80 ? GetCharStart(ref arr, index - 1) : index;
```

Next, we want to get each section. The easiest way is to use a state-machine (or abuse, depending on how you look at it) to return the sections:

```csharp
public static IEnumerable<byte[]> GetByteSections(byte[] utf8Array, int sectionCount)
{
    var sectionStart = 0;
    var sectionEnd = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < sectionCount; i++)
    {
        sectionEnd = i == (sectionCount - 1) ? utf8Array.Length : GetCharStart(ref utf8Array, (int)Math.Round((double)utf8Array.Length / sectionCount * i));
        yield return GetSection(ref utf8Array, sectionStart, sectionEnd);
        sectionStart = sectionEnd;
    }
}
```

Now I built this in this manner because I want to use `Parallel.ForEach` to demonstrate the result, which makes it *super* easy if we have an `IEnumerable`, and it also allows me to be *extremely* lazy with the processing: we only continue to gather sections when needed, which means we can lazily process it and do it *on-demand*, which is a good thing, no?

Lastly, we need to be able to get a section of bytes, so we have the `GetSection` method:

```csharp
public static byte[] GetSection(ref byte[] array, int start, int end)
{
    var result = new byte[end - start];
    for (var i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
    {
        result[i] = array[i + start];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Finally, the demonstration:

```csharp
var sourceText = "Some test 平仮名, ひらがな string that should be decoded in parallel, this demonstrates that we work flawlessly with Parallel.ForEach. The only downside to using `Parallel.ForEach` the way I demonstrate is that it doesn't take order into account, but oh-well.";
var source = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceText);
Console.WriteLine(sourceText);

var results = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
Parallel.ForEach(GetByteSections(source, 10),
                    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 },
                    x => { Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(x)); results.Add(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(x)); });

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Assemble the result: ");
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", results.Reverse()));
Console.ReadLine();
```

The result:

> ```
> Some test ???, ???? string that should be decoded in parallel, this demonstrates that we work flawlessly with Parallel.ForEach. The only downside to using `Parallel.ForEach` the way I demonstrate is that it doesn't take order into account, but oh-well.
>
> Some test ???, ??
> ?? string that should b
> e decoded in parallel, thi
> s demonstrates that we work
>  flawlessly with Parallel.
> ForEach. The only downside
> to using `Parallel.ForEach`
>  the way I demonstrate is
> that it doesn't take order into account, but oh-well.
>
> Assemble the result:
> Some test ???, ???? string that should be decoded in parallel, this demonstrates that we work flawlessly with Parallel.ForEach. The only downside to using `Parallel.ForEach` the way I demonstrate is that it doesn't take order into account, but oh-well.
> ```

Not perfect, but it does the job. If we change `MaxDegreesOfParallelism` to a higher value, our string gets jumbled:

> ```
> Some test ???, ??
> e decoded in parallel, thi
>  flawlessly with Parallel.
> ?? string that should b
> to using `Parallel.ForEach`
> ForEach. The only downside
> that it doesn't take order into account, but oh-well.
> s demonstrates that we work
>  the way I demonstrate is
> ```

So, as you can see, super easy. You'll want to make modifications to allow for correct order-reassembly, but this should demonstrate the trick.

If we modify the `GetByteSections` method as follows, the last section is no longer ~2x the size of the remaining ones:

```csharp
public static IEnumerable<byte[]> GetByteSections(byte[] utf8Array, int sectionCount)
{
    var sectionStart = 0;
    var sectionEnd = 0;
    var sectionSize = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)utf8Array.Length / sectionCount);

    for (var i = 0; i < sectionCount; i++)
    {
        if (i == (sectionCount - 1))
        {
            var lengthRem = utf8Array.Length - i * sectionSize;
            sectionEnd = GetCharStart(ref utf8Array, i * sectionSize);
            yield return GetSection(ref utf8Array, sectionStart, sectionEnd);
            sectionStart = sectionEnd;
            sectionEnd = utf8Array.Length;
            yield return GetSection(ref utf8Array, sectionStart, sectionEnd);
        }
        else
        {
            sectionEnd = GetCharStart(ref utf8Array, i * sectionSize);
            yield return GetSection(ref utf8Array, sectionStart, sectionEnd);
            sectionStart = sectionEnd;
        }
    }
}
```

The result:

> ```
> Some test ???, ???? string that should be decoded in parallel, this demonstrates that we work flawlessly with Parallel.ForEach. The only downside to using `Parallel.ForEach` the way I demonstrate is that it doesn't take order into account, but oh-well. We can continue to increase the length of this string to demonstrate that the last section is usually about double the size of the other sections, we could fix that if we really wanted to. In fact, with a small modification it does so, we just have to remember that we'll end up with `sectionCount + 1` results.
>
> Some test ???, ???? string that should be de
> coded in parallel, this demonstrates that we work flawless
> ly with Parallel.ForEach. The only downside to using `Para
> llel.ForEach` the way I demonstrate is that it doesn't tak
> e order into account, but oh-well. We can continue to incr
> ease the length of this string to demonstrate that the las
> t section is usually about double the size of the other se
> ctions, we could fix that if we really wanted to. In fact,
>  with a small modification it does so, we just have to rem
> ember that we'll end up with `sectionCount + 1` results.
>
> Assemble the result:
> Some test ???, ???? string that should be decoded in parallel, this demonstrates that we work flawlessly with Parallel.ForEach. The only downside to using `Parallel.ForEach` the way I demonstrate is that it doesn't take order into account, but oh-well. We can continue to increase the length of this string to demonstrate that the last section is usually about double the size of the other sections, we could fix that if we really wanted to. In fact, with a small modification it does so, we just have to remember that we'll end up with `sectionCount + 1` results.
> ```

And finally, if for some reason you split into an *abnormally large* number of sections compared to input size (my input size of ~578 bytes at 250 chars demonstrates this) you'll hit an `IndexOutOfRangeException` in `GetCharStart`, the following version fixes that:

```csharp
public static int GetCharStart(ref byte[] arr, int index)
{
    if (index > arr.Length)
    {
        index = arr.Length - 1;
    }

    return (arr[index] & 0xC0) == 0x80 ? GetCharStart(ref arr, index - 1) : index;
}
```

Of course this leaves you with a bunch of empty results, but when you reassemble the string doesn't change, so I'm not even going to bother posting the full scenario test here. (I leave it up to you to experiment.)

Answer (score 0):

Great answer Mathieu and Der, adding a python variant 100% based on your answer which works great:

```
def find_utf8_split(data, bytes=None):

  bytes = bytes or len(data)

  while bytes > 0 and data[bytes - 1] & 0xC0 == 0x80:
    bytes -= 1

  if bytes > 0:
    if data[bytes - 1] & 0xE0 == 0xC0: bytes = bytes - 1
    if data[bytes - 1] & 0xF0 == 0xE0: bytes = bytes - 1
    if data[bytes - 1] & 0xF8 == 0xF0: bytes = bytes - 1

  return bytes
```

This code finds a UTF-8 compatible split in a given byte string.  It does not do the split as that would take more memory, that is left to the rest of the code.

For example you could:

```
position = find_utf8_split(data)
leftovers = data[position:]
text = data[:position].decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the last four if statements?

Comment: The first IF identifies a continuation byte. The last four IFS unwind a full or partial byte continuation sequence back to the origin. Thus ensuring the end of a full byte sequence is returned.

Comment: I was wondering why it isn't `while bytes > 0 and data[bytes] & 0xC0 == 0x80: bytes -= 1; return bytes`. Also, the first line should be `if bytes is None: bytes = len(data)` because `(0 or len(bytes)) == len(bytes)`.