# How to split an array of bytes avoiding to truncate in the middle of an unicode extended grapheme cluster

Tags: perl

Say we have an arbitrary long array of bytes read with the `sysread()` Perl function that we have to split in a fixed number of CHARS avoiding to truncate in the middle of an unicode grapheme.
As an example, say we have to split an array of bytes in chunks of 5 CHARS and that we have the following byte sequence:

```
0x61 0x62 0x63 0x64 0x65    0xcc 0x81 0x61 0x62 0x63 0x64 0xe2 0x82 0xac
```

Reading the last byte of the first 5 bytes (`0X65`) we get that it is a valid grapheme (char `e`) and scanning byte per byte the second byte sequence rightward and testing (using the `\X` matcher) the increasing sequence (first `0xCC`, then `0xCC 0x81`) we get that the sequence `0xCC 0x81` is also a valid grapheme (a non printable char or a strange space), but the correct grapheme is `0x65 0xCC 0x81` (char `é`).

My try was, starting from the cut point (e.g. between 5th and 6th byte), to test if the left byte (in our case `0x65`) falls or not in the `[\xC0-\xFF]` range.
If NOT: add byte per byte from the right sequence and truncate the sequence when the matcher `/^\X$/` returns false and this approach in my tests worked fine.

My problem is that when the last byte of first sequence falls in the range `[\xC0-\xFF]` it means I might be in the middle of a grapheme and then I go crazy because I can't figure out how to correctly identify the boundaries of the grapheme cluster (as they may be arbitrarily long).

Note 1: I can't UTF-8 encode the whole input file and work at CHAR level because I have to deal with files of some TB and the performance is a must.

Note 2: I read the excellent Tom Chirstiansen's [Perl Unicode Cookbook](https://www.perl.com/pub/2012/04/perlunicook-standard-preamble.html/) and it helped me a lot to better understand some Unicode basis but not to find a way to solve my problem.

Any help or tip would be really appreciated

PS: Should I consider using the C++ ICU library instead of Perl?

**UPDATE**  I omitted for sake of semplicity that I don't scan the whole file, but I do a parallel processing of fixed length chunks of the file using the `sysread()` with an offset.. then I  use the `sysseek()` on each chunk boundary to look ahead or backward, searching for the grapheme boundaries.

Comment: I think I would look into, instead of reading a block of bytes at a time, reading a codepoint at a time and appending to a string until the next codepoint starts a new grapheme.

Comment: @Shawn I omitted for sake of semplicity that I don't scan the whole file but I do a parallel processing of fixed length chunks of the file using the sysread with an offset.. then I  use the sysseek to look ahead or backward, searching for the grapheme boundaries.

Comment: Wait ... so your main problem is what you don't say -- how to split a file (with unicoe) for reading in parallel?

Comment: @zdim RE "I don't get the five-character restriction ": The 5 bytes restriction is to simplify the case. I do a parallel read of files ~ 2TB, each worker reading buffers  of 2*1024*1024 bytes at every iteration.
The reason why I read the chunks at byte-level using the `sysread()` is that the sysread is more than 50 times faster of `read` on a utf-8 filehandle. For instance, a single worker that reads a 2GB file tooks ~7 sec using the `read()` and 0.11 sec using the `sysread()`

Comment: @zdim RE "how to split a file (with unicoe) for reading in parallel?" Partially true, but I can't split files on the filesystem, my task is to do a parallel read of file chunks, process these chunks in parallel in memory (doing some EBCDIC encoding) and do a multiplexed transmission ot these streams to a mainframe system, where the counterpart reassemble the chunks on-the-fly and store the resulting file as Mainframe dataset.

Comment: So you wanna decode byte sequence into perl's utf8 string by youself to get a speed?

Comment: @gapsf nope, I wanna pass consistent byte sequences to an EBCDIC encoder without doing an intermediate UTF8 decoding.

Comment: So problem is with last bytes in the block?

Comment: @gapsf  My goal is to detect if I'm truncating in the middle of a grapheme and then move forward to the correct grapheme boundary and then truncate there the sequence.

Comment: Ok. You scan bytes from the begining of the block using regexp to match next valid graphem?

Comment: @gapsf that's was my try, but in my post you can see that either the last byte of the first sequence and the first two bytes ot the second one are valid grapheme, but in reality I'm breaking the `0x65 0xCC 0x81` grapheme, causing a data corruption.

Comment: Suppose after last graphem match you have yet another one byte in the block. Read next 3 bytes and try to match this 4 bytes. Graphem is 4 bytes long maximum.

Comment: "_can't split files on the filesystem_" -- sure, I meant how to decide where to start processing (where to seek) in each chunk.  That helped, I am removing some of my comments to clear up the air here :)

Comment: Ah, i get it. You cant correctly decode utf byte sequence starting from arbitrary byte position. To split bytes correctly you should decode from very begging, cut only after graphem match and continue. In other words you cant cut right without encoding from start of utf byte sequences. So you cannot split byte sequence to decode pieces in parallel.

Comment: @gapsf exactly what I hoped could be avoided :-/

Comment: It seems impossible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953069/perl-trim-utf8-bytes-to-length-and-sanitize-the-data

Comment: @gapsf, That's not what my answer says. It only says that properties aren't enough

Comment: @gapsf It is precisely that response from Ikegami that inspired me in an attempt to try to identify the boundaries of a grapheme starting from an arbitrary byte position :-)

Comment: @ikegami but your example means we cant split bytes just where we want. We should decode to split at right position. But Hannibal want split before decoding. Am i wrong?

Comment: Let's assume you read in a chunk which is a sequence of valid Unicode chars ... and then a byte or a few which don't form a valid grapheme (just happened to get cut off there). I'd still say that you let Perl decode it, in a way so that it would flag invalid parts (`decode(... FB_CROAK)` or some such?).  So it'll hopefully read all correct unicode up to the point at which there's just a byte or two remaining and will flag them. ...

Comment: [cont'd] Then a simple analysis lets you know which part of the whole chunk is valid to pass on, and the rest could be saved to a file to be patched with (an incomplete) beginning of the next chunk.  Hopefully this can detect the invalid beginning as well (but I am not sure at all)

Comment: Is it work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45201142/find-nearest-safe-split-in-byte-array-containing-utf-8-data

Comment: From what i read all talking how find code point boundary not a grapheme boundary

Comment: I'm thinking that you may need a little "post-mortem" analysis.  Let's say the last or the first part of the chunk is read as `e` -- is it indeed meant to be that or is just a part of what is meant to be `é` (`\x{0065}\x{0301}` cut between the code points, so valid UTF-8)? (See ikegami's answer linked above.) Well, you can't tell.  Except, that once processing of all chunks is completed one can stitch together and analyze  end-of-one + beginning-of-next.  A hassle but I don't see how else to do it.

Comment: @zdim that was my first idea (to combine the `\X` or the `decode(...FB_CROAK)` but it isn't enough because in the example of my post the `0x65` trailing byte of first sequence is matched as valid grapheme then the chunk seems cut correctly at `0x65` but it isn't. I think that a valid approach could be to try to add the next bytes one by one and check if the last valid codepoint (`0x65`) plust the added byte(s) match a valid grapheme. But I think that this approach should be mixed with the utf-8 properties to detect invalid utf8 sequences and break the heuristic decode.

Comment: "_that was my first idea ..._" -- yup, see my comment just above, posted at nearly the same time!

Comment: But how you start decoding Nth block without knowing where last grapheme stops in Nth-1 block? Isnt it force you decode blocks sequentally?

Comment: @zdim yep... It's a shame .. I was hoping to speed up the technology I am developing by 50 times, but apparently I will have to settle for a "I can't do it" :-D

Comment: @gapsf That's why I was searching for a way to identify the boudaries of a (maybe) grepheme cluster :-) The files I have to deal to are TB of ASCII with some currency simbols but there is not a specific rule, the users are free to put inside these financial reports any kind of character, so these files are to be treated as utf-8.

Comment: https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/tr29-39.html

Comment: @gapsf thx, I've already read the Unicode standards, but that document describes a set of rules based on a codepoint approach and not at byte-level. I think a possible solution might be the use of the C++ ICU library (released by the Unicode consortium) but I have to study on it.

Comment: @gapsf I hadn't noticed the second-last link you shared. It's interesting .. I don't know if it can work or not, probably only Ikegami knows :-) but I'll try. thank you

Comment: Random access unicode.org/reports/tr29/tr29-39.html#Random_Access  From what i can figure out at least there are the rules for grapheme boundaries detection but can't understand what these rules are exactly.

Comment: @gapsf I don't want to implement the whole Unicode specifications :-)))) but the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45201142/find-nearest-safe-split-in-byte-array-containing-utf-8-data) you shared is very useful... I'm writing a small C++ program to test its correctness.

Comment: @Hannibal  But you can easly find codepoints from bytestream and go from codepoints to graphemes?

Comment: '_apparently I will have to settle for a "I can't do it"_" -- did you try to `decode` a string that starts and ends with a few loose bytes (perhaps valid utf8 but not a whole grapheme, or not at all) and the bulk of it are good unicode chars?   That might just give you enough to decide what the "beggining" and "end' are.  Then all else is possible.

Comment: Studing a little bit more the UTF-8 encoding I found that a continuation byte of a codepoint starts with `0b10...`.  So I can simply analyze the byte on which I'm trying to truncate the sequence and check with a bitwise AND (`( $byte & 0xC0) == 0x80 )`) if it's in a middle of a codepoint or not, then look ahead for the next byte not starting with `0b10...` and truncate the sequence. Of course it's not enough because I can still break a grapheme cluster but with some additional logic looking at the previous codepoint and testing with the `\X` matcher I can identify the grapheme cluster.

Comment: @Hannibal : when thinking about `UTF-8`, I found it a lot easier to think in terms of octals than hex. `256-bytes` worth of octals range from `\000 - \377` - so basically 4 quadrants. 1st quadrant are the 0-9 digits, most `ASCII` punctuation and control bytes, 2nd quadrant are all the english letters reside (plus tiny bits of punctuation and 1 control byte (`DEL \177 x7F`). 3rd quadrant are the `UTF-8` continuation bytes, and 4th quadrant, minus 1st 2 bytes and last 11 bytes of the quadrant, are your `UTF-8` multi-byte codepoint leading bytes.

Comment: @Hannibal : ….. and if you think in terms of octal wraparounds, then all the bytes you shouldn't expect to see in printed text, would range would `\365 - \37` (or you can write it as `\765 - \437` if the 5-digit straight helps. Even case changing is easier to think from octals, cuz uppers go from `\101-\132` and lowers `\141-172`, so you're simply adding a `4 x 8 ^ 1`, exactly `32 bytes`. Visual mnemonics exists for octals in some unique situations - say upper case letter `I (for India)`, hex is `0x49` but octals is `\111`, sharing basically the same shape as `I`.

Comment: @Hannibal : even regular `UTF-8` are made easier via octals. Take `U + 4567 ( # 17,767 ) ::: [   䕧  ] ` ::::: The octal code for 17767 is `04 .. 25 … 47`, and the 3 bytes are exactly those, high bits padded :::::: :::::::::::: :::::: ::::::::::::::::`\344 \225 \247`

Answer (score 0):

A working solution is to analyze the surroundings of the byte stream at the cut you want to make. The only limitation is that you must set a maximum length of bytes that can make up a grapheme cluster.

In correspondence with the offset in which the sequence of bytes is to be cut, a range of bytes must be selected which includes the last bytes of the first chunk (equal to the maximum bytes limit set for a grapheme cluster) and as many bytes of the beginning of the next chunk.
In this way we can be sure to find at least one complete grapheme cluster within the analyzed bytes.

The module [Unicode::GCString](https://metacpan.org/pod/Unicode::GCString) is used to identify the grapheme clusters in the range of bytes analyzed.

The program below cuts the sequence of bytes by excess: if the last grapheme cluster of a chunk has bytes in the next chunk, the cut takes place at that point. This means that the last chunk will be a few bytes shorter than the others, but adding some logic can better balance the distribution of bytes. The program is purely demonstrative and does not partition the byte sequence but only prints the offsets in which to truncate the sequence.

```
binmode STDOUT, ':utf8' ; # avoid wide char warning 
use Encode qw( decode_utf8 encode_utf8 ) ;
use Unicode::GCString ;

# --- Config ---
my $partitions             = 8 ;
my $max_bytes_per_grapheme = 10 ;

# --- Create a byte sequence sample (1000 grapheme cluster) ---
my @graphemes = (
    [ 0x61 ],                                       # a
    [ 0xC2, 0xAE ],                                 # ®
    [ 0x67, 0xCC, 0x88 ],                           # g̈
    [ 0xC3, 0x80, 0xCC, 0x88 ],                     # À̈
    [ 0x6F, 0xCC, 0x88, 0xCC, 0xB2 ],               # ö̲
    [ 0xC6, 0x81, 0xCC, 0x88, 0xCD, 0x9C ],         # Ɓ̈͜
    [ 0x6F, 0xCC, 0x88, 0xCC, 0xB2, 0xCD, 0x9C ]    # ö̲͜
) ;
my @bytes = map { @{ $graphemes[ int rand 7 ] } } ( 1 .. 1000 ) ;

my $index = 0 ;
my $offset = int( @bytes / $partitions ) ;

printf "Bytes: %d - Partitions: %d - Optimal offset: %d\n\n", scalar( @bytes ),$partitions,$offset ;

for ( 1 .. $partitions - 1 ) {

    my $l_index = $index + $offset - $max_bytes_per_grapheme ; # last bytes of partition
    my $r_index = $index + $offset + $max_bytes_per_grapheme ; # first bytes of next partition

    # --- Get bytes slice to analyze ---
    my @bytes_to_analyze = @bytes[ $l_index .. $r_index ] ;

    # --- Decode bytes as UTF-8 string ---
    my $utf8_string = decode_utf8( join '', map chr, @bytes_to_analyze ) ;

    # --- Create GCString object ---
    my $gcstring = Unicode::GCString->new( $utf8_string ) ;

    my $grapheme ;
    my $grapheme_index = 0 ;
   
    # --- Iterate over extended grapheme clusters ---
    while ( $grapheme = $gcstring->next ) {

        my $bytes_count = length( encode_utf8( $grapheme ) ) ;
        die "Grapheme cluster $grapheme is too long: $bytes_count bytes" 
           if $bytes_count > $max_bytes_per_grapheme ; 

        $grapheme_index += $bytes_count ;

        last if $grapheme_index >= $max_bytes_per_grapheme ;
    }

    $index += $offset - $max_bytes_per_grapheme + $grapheme_index ;
    print "Can truncate at grapheme: $grapheme - byte index: $index\n" ;
}
```

Output:

```
Bytes: 3957 - Partitions: 8 - Optimal offset: 494

Can truncate at grapheme: g̈ - byte index: 495
Can truncate at grapheme: ö̲͜ - byte index: 995
Can truncate at grapheme: Ɓ̈͜ - byte index: 1493
Can truncate at grapheme: À̈ - byte index: 1989
Can truncate at grapheme: Ɓ̈͜ - byte index: 2487
Can truncate at grapheme: ö̲ - byte index: 2981
Can truncate at grapheme: g̈ - byte index: 3476
```